# SharePoint webparts page that consumes webservices times out on not to heavy load.

Tags: .net, wcf, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint page that loads six webparts, each one of them consumes a wcf service. There are also some ajax calls to the webservice that is done pr request.

After loading the page about 10-20 times the page stops loading. All i get from SharePoint logs is that the request times out.

When debugging the problem, it seems like the webservices are called eventually, only waaaay late. About 4-5 minutes after initially requesting the page and the error message is displayed in SharePoint.

The webservices and Sharepoint installation is on the same windows 2008 server. On development, where this problem occurs most frequently, sql 2008 is also installed on the same server (dont tell me, i know, should be different).

If i leave it for about 15-20 minutes, with no request to the server, the page loads fine again. No other pages on sharepoint is effected, even though they might use webservices as well.

Comment: What version of SharePoint? Do you have access to a JavaScript debugger that can show you what is going on with regard to those requests? Can you try disabling web parts in turn to see whether any specific web-part is causing the problem or if it only happens in combination? I have known SharePoint to create hundreds of intermediate/temporary javascript objects for no good reason. Also did you know there was a SharePoint specific SO site? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Didnt know about hte SO site :) 

I use SharePoint 2010, we narrowed the bug down to webservices calling to sharepoint again to look for user credentials, basically clogging the system and creating the timeout.
The error seem to be because theres not enough iron on the server to deal with all requests, essentially stopping everything at one point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to my WCF service calling back to SharePoint asking for user roles and permission levels. After a certain amount of hits, SharePoint stopped responding to WCF service, which in turn stopped responding to SharePoint, causing a big mess.

For now, i haven't done much to fix it other than making sure the servers are not too busy, it doesn't seem to cause a problem in production yet, as the problem only occurs under heavy load on production server.